# Building with ember CLI in production environment

Tags: ember-cli

Running ember server works fine locally on my dev machine but how do I do it on my host? All I can do is upload the dist folder which contains the output of the CLI build. But when I navigate to it there is a blank page.

Comment: Are you building before uploading?

Comment: Ember server is just for local development, what you want to do in order to deploy to a host ( assuming the host has a web server running, nginx apache... ) `ember build --environment production` and grab the outputed files from dist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ember serve/server/s fires up a server for local development, you shouldn't use it's files to deploy on a live host.

> Starts up the server. Default port is 4200. Use --proxy flag to proxy all ajax requests to the given address. For example ember server --proxy `http://127.0.0.1:8080` will proxy all your apps XHR to your server running at port 8080.

When you want to deploy you will need to build your files in order to concat/min/uglify for that you will need to run `ember build --environment production` change the env depending on your needs.

> Builds the application depending on the environment.

To learn more about ember-cli commands refer to [this section](http://www.ember-cli.com/#using-ember-cli) of the docs.