# Ember imported lib does not include in production build version

Tags: ember.js

I have import an external lib using code snippet below in `ember-cli-build.js` file,

```
app.import('./bower_components/js-combinatorics/combinatorics.js');
```

It works fine in development mode, however, when after `ember build -prod` browser complains the lib cannot be found.

It is also works fine in normal build, `ember build`

Reference, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38268376/2226315

Comment: try this command `ember build --environment=production`

Comment: I thought `ember build -prod` is equivalent to the command you provide. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38268376/2226315

Comment: I have tried use full flat but issue persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It will work correctly without `./`

Refer this [issue](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/6829)

Comment: I should search issues first before asking. Thanks @kumkanillam

Comment: Some will get an search result easily through SO too